# Spring Batch - more than one writer based on field value

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am working on spring batch, for writer currently using FlatFileItemWriter.

I would like to write my input file content to more than one flat file based on some field value. Is Spring batch support any kind of functionality by default.[something similar to CompositeItemWriter]

For example, my input file content is something like this.

```
john,35,retail,10000
joe,34,homeloan,20000
Amy,23,retail,2000
```

Now i would like to write two different files based on third column, it means row 1 and row 3 should go to file1 and row 2 should go to file2.

My writer configuration is:

```
<bean id="fileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">

        <property name="resource" value="file:C:/output.dat"/>

        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="field1,field2...." />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`.  This `ItemWriter` implementation allows you to define a `Classifier` that chooses which of the defined delegate `ItemWriter` instances to delegate to.  In your case, you'd create a `Classifier` that decided based on field4 and delegate the writing to the appropriate instance of the `FlatFileItemWriter`.

You can read more about the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html

Comment: Thanks @Michael Minella . do you have any code example for this?

Comment: You can take a look at my book (Pro Spring Batch).  That section is available online here: https://books.google.com/books?id=1QGyKvGu1t4C&pg=PA326&lpg=PA326&dq=classifiercompositeitemwriter+example&source=bl&ots=TJXozv7tox&sig=cvFm8NKl0Ad9OvRg_HDEJsOqLbI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c9YmVfDbCM-wogTe2oCIDQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=classifiercompositeitemwriter%20example&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html)

> Calls one of a collection of ItemWriters for each item, based on a
>   router pattern implemented through the provided Classifier.

Router pattern is based on bean content

Comment: Thanks @Luca Basso Ricci.. any code example for this?